# android async task: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an async task in doInBackround I do all kind of stuff, after various sections I run a

```
 onProgressUpdate("You proceeded a bit further 1/5");
```

That works fine a multiple times until (still all in doInBackground) I have

```
HttpSessionToken = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://myserver").openConnection();
HttpSessionToken.setRequestMethod("GET");   
HttpSessionToken.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

onProgressUpdate("Still everything is working fine");
int returnCode = HttpSessionToken.getResponseCode();
onProgressUpdate("This onProgressUpdate crashes!");
```

so the last onProgressUpdate crashes, but why does it crash? Did the getResponseCode() switch the thread I am running on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't call directly the `onProgressUpdate`, you have to call `publishProgress` and let the AsynTask framework to handle the `onProgressUpdate` to be called back on the UI thread.